# Using View page, Controller and Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in Rails. And I have a project that; 
I should get a value from user in View page (for example index), and I should use the value in Helper then send the result of Helper to Controller and show the result in a new View page (for example details). Additionally I have to save results to database. Right now I have helper, controller and view pages but I can't connect these three part to each other. I need help

Controller;

```
def index
    @user = Mpeople.new[:user]
    redirect_to "secondstep"
  end

  def secondstep
    # helper should have controled here
    redirect_to "following"
  end

  def following
    @user = Mpeople.all
  end
```

Model;

```
class Mpeople < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :username
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :username
end
```

View;

```
<% form_for :user, :url => {:action => "index"} do |pform| %>

  <% pform.fields_for :person do |namefield| %>
    Twitter Name : <%= namefield.text_field :username %>
    <%= button_to "OK", :action => "following" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And helper is more longer, it sends twitter name to twitter and get following of a user from api.twitter.com

This is some of my helper; I edit it after your comment but I am not sure if  it is correct or not.

```
module FafHelper

  class PeopleController
    require 'people_helper'
    # txtname = indexteki textbox'un adına eşitle
    #txtname = tname
    txtname = namefiled.text_field
    .....
    a_get("1/users/lookup.#{json}").
                      with(:query => {:screen_name => txtname, :user_id => id_list}).
end
end
..
```

Comment: Could you show relevant code you have in the controller, model, view and helper?

Comment: It doesn't look as though you are ever calling secondstep so the helper code would not be invoked.

Comment: Yes I am aware of it. My question is that how do I connect helper, view and controller to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no need to connect views and helper as by default all the helper modules are included in the views. 
And do include the helper in you controller. Helper is a module and controller is a class. Just include the module in the class.

To get the clear picture please post exactly your structure.

Comment: This is my helper; I edit it after your comment but I am not sure if  it is correct or not.

module FafHelper
  
  class PeopleController
    require 'people_helper'
    # txtname = indexteki textbox'un adına eşitle
    #txtname = tname
    txtname = namefiled.text_field
    .....
    a_get("1/users/lookup.#{json}").
                      with(:query => {:screen_name => txtname, :user_id => id_list}).
end
end
..

Comment: If you helper is FafHelper. You can include like "include ActionView::Helpers::FafHelper". So you can use the methods availble in helper in controller. Same way you can use helper methods in views.